# I cannot use Android Studio with JDK 1.8. Does anyone else have this issue?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I originally installed Android Studio, I had it with JDK 1.7. Now JDK 8 is required to build for Android N, so I installed it. I tried redirecting the project structure to the JDK 1.8 install, but every time I push OK, it automatically goes back to JDK 1.7. Am I missing something here on updating JDK?

Comment: Restarting seemed to do the trick for me.

Comment: Did you change the JAVA_HOME in the system variables?

Comment: Anyway, Android N will be completely out only in the 3rd quarter of the year, and you can for now only use the previews.

Comment: regardless, it isn't letting me build it. i'll restart and try again later.

Comment: yup, i changed the system variable of JAVA_HOME, and it still keeps defaulting to 1.7. I uninstalled 1.7 and it still redirects to the non-existing 1.7 folder.

Comment: What is your Target API in Android project?

Comment: Are your target/compile set to API 24 in your build.gradle? Have the latest SDK updates?

Comment: Have you tried doing `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the default JDK, if you just installed the 1.8 
(most cases) you now have the 1.7 and the 1.8 installed.

if you want make sure what java you are using as default run the command.

```
 javac -version
```

and

```
 java -version
```

if is a old version you can set using the command (for Debian base Linux).

```
 sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

PS: sorry if you are using Windows I'm not able to help you,
and next time will nice to know which OS are you using .